# Can I call a LoginStatus.LoggingOut event handler from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, event-handling

I have some javascript that should log a user out after a certain period of inactive time.

I have an event handler in the code behind that handles the normal LoggingOut event of the LoginStatus object, but I can't figure out how to call it from my javascript.

I know you can use __doPostBack to call an event handler that handles the Click event of a link or button, but it doesn't seem to work for my LoginStatus object - I'm thinking it might be because it has no Click event ([here's the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus_events.aspx)) - it's not really a normal link/button.

The only other way I can think of to handle this is to create an actual logout button/link, write another event handler that does the same thing as my LoginStatus event handler, and call this new one using __doPostBack - but I don't really like this idea.

Is there any way I can call the LoggingOut event handler from my javascript?

The page:

```
// html
<asp:LoginStatus ID="loginstatus" runat="server" />
...
// js
function expireSession() {
    __doPostBack('loginstatus', ''); // doesn't seem to work
}
```

The code behind:

```
Protected Sub loginstatus_LoggingOut(ByVal sender...) Handles loginstatus.LoggingOut
    Logout() // this is my own logout sub
End Sub
```

Comment: It's normal and expected to have a logout button on every page of a site that requires you to be logged in.  Why wouldn't you want that?

Comment: The LoginStatus control displays a logout link that is used to log out - the code that I pasted there actually DOES display a logout button/link, which works correctly. BUT, my problem is that the javascript farther down tries to trigger that link, or rather the link's event handler, and can't. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a different tact.

Create a "logout" page that simply clears the cookies/session/whatever and redirects the user to a regular login page.  When the timer has elapsed do a javascript redirect to your logout page.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer! But I'm still curious as to whether there is a way to access the event handler via javascript - since you can do it with a button or link, I feel like there must be some way..

Comment: @parkker007: You could certainly create a new control that inherits from the loginstatus control and add your own button click event handler to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the proper javascript on server side by: `ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(LoginStatus1.Controls[0], null)`

But not to forget register this script with `ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(LoginStatus1.Controls[0].UniqueID);` on page render:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // required by ASP.NET to pass EnableEventValidation on page as our composed link
    // will postback from other control not original LoginStatus
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(LoginStatus1.Controls[0].UniqueID);

    base.Render(writer);
}
```